# How to persist login cookie on Facebook's browser

Tags: authentication, session-cookies

Here is my issue.

The site I am responsible for gets millions of page few per month, many from social media apps.

We are seeing an increased trend in customer service complaints along the lines of "I need to login every time I visit your site".

After some detective work, it seems that this problem is occurring mainly for people visiting from social media apps.

So it looks like this:

1. Someone logs in on their native browser.
2. Sometime later they visit the site again via a link on Facebook.
3. They are asked to log in again... frustration ensues.

Has anyone encountered anything like this and is there a way to share native browser cookies with social media apps? We can't be the first to have this issue.